# 3d.js (Force) - get current mouse position on the link for the tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to enable the tooltip when the mouse is on the line. This is the current setup that I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="graphContainer"></div>
<div id='hoveringTooltip' style='position:fixed;'></div>
```

3d.js Code - Basic Setup:

```
var width = 1200,
height = 900;

var svg = d3.select("#graphContainer").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

 var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-120)
.linkDistance(80)
.size([width, height]);

//Create all the line svgs but without locations yet
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function (link) {
        return link.thick
    })
    .attr("data-info", function (link) {
        return link.info;
    })
    .style("marker-end", "url(#suit)")
    .on("mouseover", mouseOverLink)



function mouseOverLink (e) {
//d3.select(this).style("stroke","red");
d3.select(this).attr("class", "link_selected");
 var that = this;

var value = Number( this.attributes.x1.value );

var xx = d3.select(this).attr("cx") + "px"
var yy = d3.select(this).attr("cy") + "px"
var xxx = d3.event.pageX;
var yyy =     d3.event.pageY;

var coordinates = [0, 0];
coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
var x = coordinates[0];
var y = coordinates[1];


var value = this.attributes[1].value;
$('#hoveringTooltip').show();
$('#hoveringTooltip').html(value);
$('#hoveringTooltip').css({
    "top": xxx,
    "left": yyy
});
 }
```

In the mouseOverLink function, I have tried all scenarios that I could find on SO and on internet. I do get the values for the X/Y mouse, but they are always wrong. I also tried to attach mouseover link using Jquery eventing, but those values are also wrong.

If there is another way to display the toolitip on the link, I would be more then happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not provide a working fiddle so I have made a force-directed Plunk to explain the solution.

First give style for the tool tip div like this:

```
div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;// because we are going to give the position.
    text-align: center;
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    background: lightsteelblue;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Next make a div and append it to the body like this:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);//so that its not visible initially
```

Now on link mouse over/mouse out do

```
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {//show tooltip
        tooltip.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 0.9);
            tooltip.html("<p>source:"+d.source.name+ "</p><p>target:"+d.target.name+ "</p>")//tool tip html
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");

      })
      .on("mouseout", function (d) {
            tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);//hde tooltip
          })
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gOxuHFyL6lTIDntlli8g?p=preview).

Hover over the link to see the tool tip.

Comment: WOW. This hit the spot directly. My code setup was almost identical to yours, and I just plugged your code and it works out of the box. Thank you Sir!!!

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is if you're using xxx and yyy in a css style rule, you need to add "px" to the end of the values like you do for xx and yy

Comment: Same thing. Adding "px" produces same results.